# Jupyter notebook - OSError [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

I had to install Jupyter in order to complete Udacity's projects. After following the instructions, and running Jupyter, none of the notebooks would open. This is the log output:

```
[W 06:54:04.215 NotebookApp] The signatures database cannot be opened; maybe it is corrupted or encrypted. You may need to rerun your notebooks to ensure that they are trusted to run Javascript. The old signatures database has been renamed to /home/aulon/.local/share/jupyter/nbsignatures.db.bak and a new one has been created.
[E 06:54:04.218 NotebookApp] Unhandled error in API request
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/aulon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 516, in wrapper
        result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
      File "/home/aulon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "/home/aulon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
        raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
      File "/home/aulon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 307, in wrapper
        yielded = next(result)
      File "/home/aulon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py", line 124, in get
        path=path, type=type, format=format, content=content,
      File "/home/aulon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 384, in get
        model = self._notebook_model(path, content=content)
      File "/home/aulon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 344, in _notebook_model
        self.mark_trusted_cells(nb, path)
      File "/home/aulon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/manager.py", line 456, in mark_trusted_cells
        trusted = self.notary.check_signature(nb)
      File "/home/aulon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 556, in __get__
        return self.get(obj, cls)
      File "/home/aulon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 535, in get
        value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
      File "/home/aulon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/manager.py", line 58, in _notary_default
        return sign.NotebookNotary(parent=self)
      File "/home/aulon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 390, in __init__
        self.store = self.store_factory()
      File "/home/aulon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 338, in factory
        return SQLiteSignatureStore(self.db_file)
      File "/home/aulon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 147, in __init__
        self.db = self._connect_db(db_file)
      File "/home/aulon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 171, in _connect_db
        os.rename(db_file, old_db_location)
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
...
```

I googled and found some similar problems [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1171), [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2301), and [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9163), without success.

I installed Anaconda, still the same problem.

Any help is much appreciated.

If I cannot solve this, how can I fully uninstall everything related to jupyter and anaconda? I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Otherwise, is there any other way I can open a python notebook without jupyter? Maybe Spyder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!

It was a permission error.

Follow the link [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2621#issuecomment-312672865) if you are having the same problem.

Comment: In general, please provide a summary of any links you provide, as those links can disappear over time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Windows OS try this solution. The issue is because of permission by Windows Defender.

1. Go to "Windows Defender Security Center"
2. Scroll & Click on "Virus & threat protection settings"
3. Scroll down to "Controlled folder access"
4. Make sure is Disabled